# Get Joomla3 user data in external html page

Tags: php, joomla, external

I have a joomla3 website,i built an external html page which is a client side app(jquery),visibile only to logged in users.
The page is in a directory in the webserver's root.

I would have on the top of this html page the data of the current user.
Is that possible?

I didn't find nothing that work in my situation.
Seems JFactory doesn't exist in joomla3.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I notice you've asked a supplementary question in the answers. It's best not to do that, since it usually gets missed, and answers are meant only for, well, answers! I've asked a mod to remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the whole framework in order to get access to its parts. Take the main `index.php` as an example for how to do that. Instead of routing and dispatching, put your code in there.

**standalone-script.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Constant that is checked in included files to prevent direct access.
 */
define('_JEXEC', 1);

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
{
    include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Initialise the application.
$app->initialise();

// Your code goes here...
```

Comment: Thanks."Instead of routing and dispatching, put your code in there."What you mean by that??I've to modify directly the index.php??Or I've to an external php script with the following code??And at that point,where you say " //your code goes here... " i need only to call jfactory methods for user info??Thanks in advance

Comment: The script in the example is merely a *copy* of the `index.php` with all the necessary stuff in it. **Never ever touch the original files**, if don't know *exactly* what you're doing. -- After `// Your code goes here` you have full access to the Joomla! environment, including the current user.

Comment: Yeah mate of course,i made a stand alone script that i will include in every page i need...now it works!! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Exists as far as I know https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/factory.php

Take a look at error php and that may help you get an idea of how to so a stand alone page. Note however ha you need to give the platform from a standalone application you need to make sure you are pointing at the right folder.